# Y-h Ribon Olam tune origin

Tags: song-poetry

Of the tunes used for Y-h (Kah) Ribon Olam (even if used originally for another song), which is the first, and when was it composed and where? I know that the piyyut itself was composed in the 16th century but I haven't found anything regarding the melodies themselves.

Comment: Any tune for Lekha Dodi or Shir HaMaalot or Adon Olam works. How could we know which tune was first?

Comment: It would depend on which was composed first. It doesn't need to have been composed specifically for Y-h Ribon; I'll edit it to note that.

Comment: Vague question. Are you referring to some specific tune? I assume you mean "Kah Ribbon" in the Shabbat zemirot? (You may want to edit that into your question - not too many readers know that reference.)

Comment: I'm referring to whichever was composed first- I don't know which is the oldest, and I'd like to know that and its history. I haven't found many resources as to the history of the tunes' compositions, let alone those that are applicable to Y-h Ribon.

Comment: Avram, I see that someone answered, and I assume the vote is yours. I'm still extremely unclear as to what tune your talking about, and if you can modify your question to clarify that, I think it would help all of us appreciate both the question and the answer. 3 people, including I, have voted to close this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not believe we know how the original tune went but we know [from the author himself](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45788&st=&pgnum=12&hilite=), R. Israel Najara, that the tune for this particular song was taken from an Arabic song 'ya rabbi salim salimi' and its mode (maqam) was Rast.